# Django email account verification

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a Django project and I am trying to add Django user email account verification. Everything looks fine, but after I receive the email and try to activate the account with the activation URL I get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /activate/h46fdg5h46fdg5h46fdghfd8hfdhfd48hfd4h6
no such table: registry_profile
```

here is my activation code in view.py:

```
def activation(request, key):
    activation_expired = False
    already_active = False
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, activation_key=key)
    if profile.user.is_active == False:
        if timezone.now() > profile.key_expires:
            activation_expired = True
            id_user = profile.user.id
        else:
            profile.user.is_active = True
            profile.user.save()
    else:
        already_active = True
    return render (request,'activation.html',locals())
```

Here is my models.py file:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Did you forgot to migrate your database with the model `registry.Profile`?

Comment: I just ran the >>>manage.py migrate, isn't that enough?

Comment: @blacklwhite Yes. I got it I had to run makemigrations registry :) tnx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I got it. I had to run:

```
>>> manage.py makemigrations registry
```

and then :

```
>>> manage.py migrate
```

for more information look at:

[Django Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/)